# Showing equivalence with reversible systems

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to prove that following system,

$$x'= y$$
$$y'= x \cos y$$

is reversible.

A system is reversible if $x'=f(x,y),y'=g(x,y)$ remains the same after you apply the transform $t\to -t,y\to-y$

So then how do I calculate $$\frac{dx}{d(-t)}=y$$

and,

$$\frac{d(-y)}{d(-t)}=x \cos y$$

Comment: @jameselmore thanks for the edit, would you be able to help me with my problem?

Comment: @Moo yes thanks for your submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a reversible system to be any second-order system that is invariant under $t \rightarrow −t$ and $y \rightarrow −y$. For example, any system of the form
$$x' = f(x, y) \\ y' = g(x, y)$$
where $f$ is odd in $y$ and $g$ is even in $y$ (that is, $f(x, −y) = −f(x, y)$ and $g(x, −y) = g(x, y))$ is reversible.

We have

$$\begin{align} x' &= f(x, y) = y \\ y' &= g(x, y) = x \cos y \end{align}$$

Thus

$$\begin{align} f(x, -y) &= - y = -f(x, y) \\ g(x, -y) &= x \cos(-y) = x \cos y = g(x, y) \end{align}$$